# how to check a windows long running console task?

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task, console

I have scheduled Microsoft Windows server console application (that output to stdout) using the task scheduler .  It is long running and might take weeks to finish. Is there a way to "tap" into the console output on demand to check on the task's progress ?

Comment: is there a programming way to do it ? Perhaps I can ask programmers in Stackoverflow , should I ?

Comment: Umm... log onto the console and check it?

Comment: but it is running in the background via the windows task scheduler. Is there a way to tap into what it is printing to a console stream (such as stdout , stderr .. etc ) ?  BTW , it is a robocopy task copying a lot of files over a slow WAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the /LOG switch on the robocopy command, tail the log file.